# Copy JSON directly from web URL to couchDB with cURL

Tags: json, curl, couchdb

Is it possible to insert the result of a `curl -X GET` (which is JSON) directly into a couchDB database?

ie something like.

```
>>> curl -X GET -H "some_header" http://some_web_JSON -X POST http://127.0.0.1:port/some_DB/_bulk_docs
```

Splitting the process up seems to work but, I can't seem to get the syntax right to do it in one go (presupposing it's even possible)

```
>>>  curl -X GET -H "some_header" http://some_web_JSON > outfile.json
>>>  curl @outfile.json -X POST http://127.0.0.1:port/some_DB/_bulk_docs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As often in such cases, the good old Unix pipe combined with reading from stdin is the solution:

```
curl http://example.com/ | curl -s -T - -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/test/_bulk_docs
```